# How to Grey out a Div and set a time out

Tags: jquery, html

so i have a `div` and i would like it to be grayed out for 10 seconds and then be normal is this possible using jquery's Time out function and how would one implement it i am a noob in jquery so if some one can assist me

something like making the div un-clickable

```
<div id="grayout">
  Some Content Here
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the jQuery function delay to add a class, wait 10 seconds then queue another function to remove it:

```
$("#grayout").addClass("gray").delay(10000).queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass("gray");
    next();
});
```

Where gray in your CSS looks something like this:

```
.gray{
     // Disable div, make gray etc
     background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/xOxyRy

Comment: `delay()` will not work with `addClass` and `removeClass`

Comment: Oops, thanks @Satpal! Corrected to incorporate queue, followed by delay instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval

setInterval(function(){ $("#grayout").css("background-color","none") }, 10000);

but first you must set the grey color to your div

Some Content Here